# What is FixedTimeDelta actually representing?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to have unity3D call a function *exactly* every `n` milliseconds. Let's set `n` at `20`.

Create a brand new, blank, Unity3D project.

Change the `.Net version` to `4` (File > Build Settings > Player Settings > Other Settings > Configuration)

Create a new script and add the following:

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Debug.Log(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    sw.Restart();
}
```

Hit Play.

You will see that you get a mix of `zeros, 29's and 30's`... 
Now go to the `TimeManager` (Edit > Project Settings > Time)

Change `Maximum Allowed Timestep` to match `Fixed Timestep` (0.02).

Hit play again.

Now you will see there are no more zeros, but still around the 30ms mark.

I know there is the `Time.fixedDeltaTime` in Unity, but should the `FixedUpdate` not be getting called every 20ms, rather than 29/30ms? It's worse if you set all properties in `TimeManager` to 1: now we see massive ( > 10ms) discrepancies.

What is going on? Why is `FixedUpdate` being called later than what Unity3D says?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you can't use a `Debug.Log` method while counting milliseconds, the method itself is slow to execute, so you should create a script which saves inside a `List` a bunch of timings and then print them in the console. Something like this:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Fixedtest : MonoBehaviour {

    List<long> myList = new List<long>();
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw;
    int i = 0;
    bool hasCountFinished = false;

    private void Start() {
        Time.fixedDeltaTime = 0.02f;            
        QualitySettings.vSyncCount = 0;
        sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        sw.Stop();
        if (i<100) {            
            myList.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);     
            i++;
            sw.Restart();
        }
    }

    private void Update() {
        if (!hasCountFinished && i>=100) {
            hasCountFinished = true;
            foreach (long myLong in myList) {
                Debug.Log(myLong);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I set the `vSync` off, it's needed in order to tell Unity NOT to wait for a full refresh cycle which is usually 16ms (60Hz), thus giving you those results even when you set `fixedDeltaTime` to 0.2.

If you use this script, you'll see that most of the results in the list will be around 20ms, clearly there'll be discrepancies due to other components of the engine, execution time of `sw.Restart()`, etc.

**EDIT:**

The first results (some 0s then a single spike higher than 300ms) are due to the scene preparation that Unity does when you press play (serialization, etc.), they're perfectly normal and you can't do anything about it.

Then the other results, as I said, depend on a lot of factors, i.e. the execution time of single lines of code which can vary due to the fact that your OS is allotting time to the Unity thread *while other processes are still running*.

Keep in mind that the `fixedDeltaTime` works this way: let's say you keep the `vSync` on, with a refresh rate of 30Hz, while you set `fixedDeltaTime = 0.2f`. This means that you want the physics engine to run its update every 20ms, regardless of what refresh rate you're using.

But the physics engine runs *inside* the main game loop of Unity, so it can be executed zero, once or more than once per single frame. So, in our example, this is what happens:

1st frame: Fixed Update, Update

Game loop waits so as to complete a single refresh rate, 33ms.

2nd frame: Since 33ms have passed since the last Fixed Update, one Fixed Update and one Update are executed.

Other 33ms waited.

3rd frame: now, since the *first* frame, 66ms have passed, and the physics engine should have updated three times from the 2nd frame (66/20 = 3.3), but until now it executed just once, so Unity will execute Fixed Update *twice* in order to keep up the consistency set by your `fixedDeltaTime`.

And this is exactly why, when keeping the `vSync` on in your original test code, you got those results, some times 16ms and some other times 33ms, since 16<20 sometimes Fixed Update would not run in a single game loop, but once every two game loops.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not make it any clearer. I ran your code and came out with the same result of an earlier test where, while *most* are ~20ms, there are a number of values waaay off. There is very little consistency. I tried this even with the camera disabled, so no rendering is done.

Comment: Further, the first few measurements are 0. Then there is a massive (I just got 508ms) spike, followed by more 0's. This doesn't seem right.

Comment: I'll amend my answer with an edit to further explain what's happening.

Comment: @pookie if the answer is satisfying please don't forget to mark it as accepted, if it's not pls tell what's missing and/or is not clear

Comment: Thanks, forgot about this.